# Tomcat docker container stops after run

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:latest

RUN ["rm", "-fr", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/webapp.war"]

ADD ./webapp/target/webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD [“catalina.sh”, “run”]
```

after building and pushing to dockerhub this img, trying to run:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:8080 abubandit/demo-app:1.0
```

```
docker ps -a
```

[docker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3iR2.png)

```
[root@centos ~]# docker logs e9349021d7e5
/bin/sh: 1: [“catalina.sh”,: not found
```

what's wrong?

Comment: As described in the logs the problem is due to the fact it does not find the script. Two solutions. Idk what's this script but if you got it locally, add a step: `ADD catalina.sh .` before your CMD

Comment: Your `CMD` has Unicode "smart" quotes; it needs to have straight quotes U+0022.  You don't need to repeat that line, though; if you delete it, it will use the (identical) [`CMD` from the Docker hub `tomcat` image](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/b67f152f3900928e81c855d3259177cd4f48ea70/10.0/jdk11/openjdk-buster/Dockerfile#L137).